# TSQL double "commit" required to commit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First, in MS SQL Server Management Studio, I've enabled `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` options. I'm not sure if that has something to do with this behaviour I'm seeing.

I've got the following script:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

WITH
    DocLinksTmp
AS
    (
    select *, 
     row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col1) as [RowNumber]
     from doctable
    )  
DELETE
    DocLinksTmp
WHERE
    RowNumber > 1 

GO
COMMIT
COMMIT

print @@trancount
```

Leaving both `COMMIT` statements, the print command prints 0. When I removed one `COMMIT`, the print statement prints 1.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Books Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx):

When `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` is ON, executing `BEGIN TRANSACTION` causes two nested transactions to open. `BEGIN_TRANSACTION` increments `@@trancount` whenever a transaction is active.

Comment: In other words, the second `COMMIT` would happen automatically after the `print` statement.